# Excel: Count cells in matrix with multiple conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table `table1` with a matrix of n columns `[[column_1]:[column_n]]` that contain dates or empty fields.
Also there's a column `[number]` with integers.

I want to count all cells that contain a date in the past AND are in a row where the corresponding number is 0. How do I do that?

Only the first condition is easy: `=COUNTIF(Table1[[column_1]:[column_n]];"<"&TODAY())`
But I don't get it to only consider rows in which the integer is 0.

I know there's probably an approach using array functions, but I can't figure it out. Searching on google was to no avail.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately Excel is not good at working with 2D ranges and lists at the same time. You need to count the values by row (`=COUNTIF(Table1[@[column_1]:[column_n]];"<"&TODAY())*(table1[@[number]]=0)`) and summarize them in a second step. (Don't forget the `@` in the formula)

Comment: Well, thanks! I guess there is a limit of what you can do without VBA, but good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to `SUMPRODUCT`:

`=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[[column_1]:[column_n]]<TODAY())*(Table1[number]=0))`

Regards

Comment: That seems like the way to go! And it returns a reasonable value, except that it also counts empty cells as dates that lie in the future. Is there a way to omit those?

Comment: Ok, I found a solution for this. (albeit not very elegant)
=SUMPRODUCT((IF(ISEMPTY(Table1[[column_1]:[column_n]]);FALSE();Table1[[column_1]:[column_n]])<TODAY())*(Table1[number]=0))
I'll still count your solution as correct, as it answered my original question

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would be useful:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[[column_1]:[column_n]];"<"&TODAY();Table1[number];"0")
```